# Why doesn't FIND_IN_SET return on NULL values

Tags: mysql, null

Can anybody explain why FIND_IN_SET isn't returning the row with the NULL value? To me it seems obvious, the string "test", isn't part of NULL, so it should return it?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/389043/2

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  result VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, result) VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'abc,test');

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE
  NOT FIND_IN_SET('test', result);
```

Comment: Null comparisons are sometimes not false but undefined. And negating undefined is not true but again undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, NULL is not a string, not even an empty one. When you compare to NULL special operators are of need, like `column IS NULL` or the NULL-safe comparator `<=>`.

Usually this is solved with a query like

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE
  NOT FIND_IN_SET('test', result)
  OR result IS NULL;
```

I for one think, that the `FIND_IN_SET()` function shouldn't exist at all. It makes it seem like having comma separated values in a column is absolutely normal and quite common. But it isn't. You shouldn't store the values this way. You have a lot of disadvantages (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) for a probably incomplete list) and you should really look into [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Like Bill says in the linked post, comma separated values violate the very first normal form already.

Comment: The `result IS NULL` is the solution I came up with. My actual use case is selecting a bunch of rows, `GROUP_CONCAT` the results, and using FIND_IN_SET on that, so I'm not actually storing CSV in the database. I'll have a read through the linked posts now, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you could avoid `FIND_IN_SET()`? Consider asking in another question, how the query could be rewritten. `FIND_IN_SET()` can't make use of an index, so this might come in handy once you deal with enough data :)

Comment: Well, for now I'm still working some kinks out (read: forced rushed deployment, retro-fixing bugs :p) with the full query, but once I'm satisfied I've got it nailed, I'll post here again for advice on improvements I could make.